# cannot assign to immutable expression of type anyobject

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, dictionary

```
var arr_contacts2 = [AnyObject]()

ViewDidLoad(){
for  contacts in info {

            var dict_contact = [String:AnyObject]()

            dict_contact["id"] = contacts.contact_id
            dict_contact["type"] = contacts.type
            dict_contact["value"] = contacts.value

            arr_contacts2.append(dict_contact)
        }
    }


IBAction(){
var dict_contact = arr_contacts2[0]
 dict_contact["value"] = "gg" //Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject?!'
}
```

Why I am getting this error?
What is the wrong with the code?

Help me to solve this.

**Thank you for your time**

Comment: try like this `if let dict_contact = arr_contacts2[0] as? [String:AnyObject] { dict_contact["value"] = "gg" }`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0, Thanks for your answer. can't I change directly into array like `arr_contacts2[0]["value"] = "gg"`?

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0, How can I directly change value of dictionary inside array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ISSUE IN YOUR CODE:**

```
var dict_contact = arr_contacts2[0] // IT ASSIGNS object of type "AnyObject" to dict_contact
//compiler couldn't possibly know, that dict_contact have a dictionary value
```

**UPDATE YOUR CODE as below**

```
func IBAction(){
    guard let dict_contact = arr_contacts2[0] as? [String:AnyObject]
        else{
            return
        }
    var contactInfo  = dict_contact
    contactInfo["value"] = "gg" //Now it should work
    }
```

***OR***

**Declare your arr_contacts2 as below**

```
var arr_contacts2 = [[String:AnyObject]]()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can't I change directly into array like arr_contacts2[0]["value"] = "gg"?

Comment: var dict_contact = arr_contacts2[0] // IT ASSIGNS object of type "AnyObject" to dict_contact
//compiler couldn't possibly know, that dict_contact have a dictionary value, So you can'd directly manipulate it, first you need to cast it!!

Comment: ok, how can I directly change value of dictionary inside array?

Comment: Declare arr_contacts2  as =>   var arr_contacts2 = [[String:AnyObject]]()

Answer (score 1):

`arr_contacts2` is of type `[AnyObject]`.

`contact` is of type `AnyObject`.

You cannot assign a `String` to `contact["value"]`.

It should work if you change `arr_contacts2` to `[[String: Any]]`.