# Swift 4, keyPath get error: cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Any'

Tags: swift4

```
public struct Person {
    var fid: Int
    var name: String
}

public struct Contact {
    var fid: Int
    var name: String
}

var pks = [\Person.fid, \Person.name]
var cks = [\Contact.fid, \Contact.name]
var p = Person(fid: 10, name: "hello")
var c = Contact(fid: 11, name: "test")

c[keyPath: cks[0]] = p[keyPath: pks[0]]
```

I want copy Contact's values to Person use swift 4 keyPath. Get an 
    error: cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Any'

I don't understand why?

```
c[keyPath: cks[0] as! WritableKeyPath<Contact, Int>] = p[keyPath: pks[0]] as! Int
```

will work. bug how can I do like this:

```
pks.indices.forEach { index in
    let pk = pks[index]
    let ck = cks[index]
    c[keyPath: ck] = p[keyPath: pk]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot assign to immutable expression of type anyobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982883/cannot-assign-to-immutable-expression-of-type-anyobject)

Comment: Not a dupe @crizzis, this refers to Swift 4 Codable Keypaths, that link just shows a lack of explicit type casting.

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm hitting the same issue but the problem seems to be that it cannot infer writeable types when you mix them:

```
var mixed = [\Person.fid, \Person.name]            // [PartialKeyPath<Person>]
var ids = [\Person.fid, \Person.sid]               // [ReferenceWriteableKeyPath<Person, Int]
var mixedIds = [\Person.fid, \Contact.fid]         // [AnyKeyPath]
var strings = [\Person.firstName, \Person.surname] // [ReferenceWriteableKeyPath<Person, String>]
```

In theory this would work:

```
let person = Person()
person[keyPath:strings[0]] = strings[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to use Swift 4 KeyPath functionality on dynamic types. The compiler needs to be able to infer the types at compile time, not run time. The error you are receiving is telling you just that - compiler can't infer value type and so can't guarantee the value can be changed.